# change typeof(DateTime) to only date using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I'm trying to add a `DateTime` column to a `DataTable`. I use that code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
```

But this requires a `DateTime` with the format "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss".

What I want is only the date. So `typeof(DateTime)` but only the date.

If you have a better way to do it, please tell me. My way is just an idea I had :)

Suggestions appreciated :)

**EDIT:**

I want to use the `DataTable` as `DataSource` of a `Telerik RadGridView`. I'm using the `CellFormatting` event and in it I try to fill the date in the RadGridView cells. Here you can see the snippet I use:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(e.CellElement.Value.ToString(), "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

This will logically show the date combined with the time. But if I change it to

```
DateTime.ParseExact(e.CellElement.Value.ToString(), "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
```

it throws and exception that this is not a valid DateTime format because I used `typeof(DateTime)` above. So it requires the time as well or else it will throw an exception.

**EDIT2:**

It's a Windows Forms application.

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't have _any_ implicit format. String representations have.

Comment: A `DateTime` doesn't *have* a format. It's just a date and a time. If you want to only format the date part, then change the format in how you're viewing the datatable.

Comment: If I change the format in how I'm viewing the table it throws an exception that it's not a valid DateTime format.

Comment: If you are just storing it in a DataTable then you shouldn't worry about the format. Only when you need to display it somewhere does it matter

Answer (score 2):

A `DateTime` has no *format*, it just has a value. You can *display* a `DateTime` with a specific format, for example without the time. Or you can truncate the time portion of a `DateTime` by using its [`Date` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx). But note that this will not remove the time portition from it; it'll just return the `DateTime` which is  midnight of the same date.

So you should still use `DateTime` as column-type and apply the format where you want to diplay this field.

For example:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    DateTime date = row.Field<DateTime>("date");
    string dateFormatted = date.ToShortDateString(); // or ToString("d") or dt.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I edited my question, please see above. I think I didn't write important things before so I edited it now :)

Comment: @Therk: one way is `DataFormatString="{0:d}"` or `DataFormatString="{0:dd.MM.yyyy}"` on the aspx at this column. It is ASP.NET, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know what you excactly mean. Do you mean on the line `dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));`? Or what/where do you mean?

Comment: @Therk: is it ASP.NET? ... oh wait, `CellFormatting` seems to be a winforms event. Give me some time.

Comment: It is .NET Windows Forms. There aren't any .aspx files. I should've mentioned it in the question. I'll edit again.

Comment: I'm not familiar with telerik controls. But [i've read here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/formatting-a-datetime-cell-as-date) that you can use: `GridViewDateTimeColumn column = (GridViewDateTimeColumn)this.radGridView1.Columns["Date"]; 
column.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dd.mm.yy}";` if the column type is `System.DateTime`.

Comment: Thats what I found first. But that didn't help me. Maybe I should as the question in a Telerik forum. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there's a difference between the data within a `DateTime` structure and the way that it is formatted.  If you only care about the date, the standard is to leave the time at 00:00:00.000.  In fact, there's a [constructor for DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx) that does exactly this.

When you format the date, what you display is up to you.  Using `ToShortDateString` might give you the output you want.

E.g.

```
DateTime myDate = new DateTime(2014, 12, 25);
string s = myDate.ToShortDateString(); // s = 12/25/2014
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping a valid DateTime object in the data source, and use the grid's abilities to change the format displayed in the cells. Here is a small example demonstrating how to achieve this.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now);
        dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));

        RadGridView grid = new RadGridView();
        this.Controls.Add(grid);
        grid.DataSource = dt;

        GridViewDateTimeColumn dateColumn = (GridViewDateTimeColumn )grid.Columns["date"];

        //this will set the format of the date displayed in the cells
        dateColumn.FormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}";

        //this will set the format of the editor - when the cell is opened for editing
        dateColumn.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateColumn.CustomFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";
```

More information about this column type is available in the [Telerik UI for WinForms documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-columns-gridviewdatetimecolumn.html).